# Values which makes my function continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
\dfrac{\ln(x+1)-e^x+1}{x}, & x>0 \\
ax, & x \le 0
\end{cases}
$$

I need the values who makes the function continuous. I calculated the limit about 0 of the first part, and the result is 0, so i suppose the limit abous 0 of the second part should be 0 too. But in this case i'll get a point and i suppose a point is not derivable. So how can i calculate the values?

Comment: You have two different definitions on the same intervals.

Comment: The limit from the right is indeed $0$. For what $a$ does $ax$ approach $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$ (from the left)?

Comment: limit ax = 0 no matter what a we choose so either any a or no a will make it continuous.  It all depends on whether the limit of the other term is 0.  I may be wrong but I calculate the limit is 1, not 0 so no a will make this continuous.  Unless I made an error on the limit.

Comment: Any negative real value makes ax approach 0 as x approaches 0 @AndréNicolas

Comment: @Marco: That's not qute right. **Any** value of $a$ works.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Being the function continous about a point doesn't means the function is derivable about the point

Comment: @Marco: Yes, differentiability at a point is much stronger than continuity. For differentiability, you might check what $a$ works. Only one will, I think it is $a=-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How can i find the value for the differentiability?

Comment: The way I did it in a mental calculation was to use the Maclaurin series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and $e^x$ (just the terms up to $x^2$).

Answer (score 1):

Applying l'hospitals rule we find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=0$

and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}ax=0=f(0)$

Thus the function is continuous at zero for every real value of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

When you have
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
f_R(x), x > a, \\
f_L(x), x \le a
\end{cases},
$$
this function is continuous if $f_L, f_R$ are continuous and
$$
\lim_{x \to a^+} f_R(x) = f_L(a).
$$